# Cannot redeclare class JModuleHelper error

Tags: php, joomla

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JModuleHelper in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\plugins\system\jat3\core\jo omla\modulehelper.php on line 30

Plzz... Help

Comment: This plugin also loading class JModuleHelper, but is already loaded by Joomla itself.

Comment: Make sure that you `include_once`/`require_once` instead of just `include`/`require`

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You need to show your code, and how you produce the error, in addition to telling us the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update your template and T3-plugin.
See [this post by Joomla Art](http://www.joomlart.com/updates/joomla-templates/huge-update-28-templates-updated-and-released-for-joomla-25x).